# Advanced shading technique for strategy game map

Tags: textures, shader, lighting, terrain

I'm a fan of RTS (real time stragy) game, and i'm working for a rts game myself!
I can produce a simple terrain map from triangle/quad. with texture tile/ blending... Now I want to move to a new level. Currently i'm using only lighting shader, with Phong shading I think with specular,diffuse color... very basic shading!

And the result is not bad, but still cant compare to current game today (like starcraft2, civilization V, shogun 2 campaing map....). For example the terrain in starcraft 2 look very shining, rich color, sharp, and cool. It doesnt need to look reality in this kind of game. It just look nice, beautiful!
For example : https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-zNtnsUV02wc/UkxFLpKmJJI/AAAAAAAAAEE/USuWhYK8JfE/w1049-h831-no/Terrain+001.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wb2j.jpg

So I know that just sampler (linear/point...) the texture is not enough (even the how nice the texture). There must be some high technique behind for current game. Like Bloom, HDR, directx 11 lighting, Bump Mapping...
Cause I'm quite new to 3d, so I'm not sure what technique is to be used. Just give me the keyword, I can search google for it (doc,source code...). Thanks!

Comment: procedural shader splatting is a nice way to texture. Deferred shading with lots of lights can also make a pretty rich scene. There are _lots of_ techniques to make a scene extremely beautiful. Check GPU gems at NVIDIA, has pretty much tuts.

Comment: and a presentation: http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1277/HALO-WARS-The-Terrain-of it has nice features too. At least for me.

Comment: Today I just extract the texture of starcraft2 (use MPQEditor), they use texture of size 1024x1024 dds file (format D3DFMT_DXT5) and a bump normal image file of same resolution. I tried to test the texture in my game, but it's quite dark, of couse it need pixel shader to make it look nice ! And after read this Article : http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/S2008-Filion-McNaughton-StarCraftII.pdf  , they seem to use a lot of Deffered Rendering, but this article mostly not about terrain rendering!